# There's a function in mysql like str_replace from php?

Tags: mysql, replace, diacritics

In my database I have a lot of people ...

Some of the people have the romanian diacritics like that : Ă-correct form ,in my database('Äƒ').

All I want to do is to replace all 'Äƒ' with 'Ă' ..just that.

`For example if I have:

```
'MÄƒDÄƒLIN' - > MĂDĂLIN,ARAMÄƒ -> ARAMĂ.
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

You may try this

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(columnname, 'find_string', 'replace_with')
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL defines a function called **REPLACE** that does exactly like PHP's **str_replace**.

You can use it to replace all occurences of a string in a column by doing :

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column,  'Äƒ', 'Ă');
```

The documentation of this function can be found at : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

All string functions for Mysql can be found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

You should try replace:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace